# Can't access the instance variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have an UTableView grouped. I want to split my data into "categories" group. I have an instance variable which contains all groups in my database.

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController {

    // Response from server
    NSString* serverResponse;
    NSMutableArray *categories;     // This NSMutableArray contains all category's server    
}

@property (strong) NSString *serverResponse;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray *categories;
```

I fill my NSMutableArray with the requestFinished method (where all works perfectly)

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{  
    NSString *result = request.responseString;

    NSArray *jsonArray = (NSArray*)[result JSONValue];

    int count = [jsonArray count]; 
    int i;
    NSDictionary *jsonDict = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];

    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        jsonDict = [jsonArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString *current = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"categoriy"];

        [categories addObject:current];
        NSLog(@"%d", [categories count]) // Shows 4 -> ok !
    }
}
```

But when I call it in this method :

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"%d", [categories count])   // Show 0 -> bad !
    return [categories count];
}
```

It shows on the consol "0" !

I really dont understand why !

Perhaps someone could help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem might be that `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` is called before the `requestFinished:` is called.

I think you have to reload the tableview.

Try putting `[self.tableView reloadData]`, or something like that, at the end of `requestFinished:`.